# How to fetch the value of l1, l2, l3 out of this map?

Tags: java, collections

How to get the value of the list out of this map?

values of all the list separately?
Please reply soon?

```
   public class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    List<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> l3=new ArrayList<String>();

    l1.add("1");
    l1.add("2");

    l2.add("a");
    l2.add("b");

    l3.add("1a");
    l1.add("2b");

    Map<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap<String,List<String>> ();
    map.put("List1",l1);
    map.put("List2",l2);
    map.put("List3",l3);
    }
    }
```

Comment: `map.get("List1")` will return you `l1`... I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
List<String> result = map.get("List1");
```

Or you can iterate through the list like this if you don't want to store it:

```
for(String x : map.get("List1")) {
    //do something
}
```